# List Storing constructer gives me an error in Dart

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I Cloned this code from github .The Code is all fine just have a problem in data.dart file 
here is the screen shot

- He is storing the constructer inside the list  VS code shows the error "Book is not a function

Can some one help me to resolve this error 
**Thanks**

[image: "]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is using dart 2, where the `new`/`const` operator to instantiate a new object isn't needed anymore.
You most likely don't have the good dart version or that feature enabled.

Either add `new` keyword before each `Book` or upgrade your dart